# Multiple UIPickerView on 1 ViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I created 2 UIPickerView Programatically. How do I make sure to hide pickerView1 when pickerView2 is about to show. Vice versa.

Thank you.

This is how I created them.

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == 1){
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 223) animated:YES];
            CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 0, 0);

            UIPickerView *pickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
            pickerView1.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
            pickerView1.dataSource = self;
            pickerView1.delegate = self;
            [pickerView1 setTag:1];
            [self.view addSubview:pickerView1];
            [pickerView1 release];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2){
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 273) animated:YES];
            CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 0, 0);

            UIPickerView *pickerView2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
            pickerView2.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
            pickerView2.dataSource = self;
            pickerView2.delegate = self;
            [pickerView2 setTag:2];
            [self.view addSubview:pickerView2];
            [pickerView2 release];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad`:

```
[pickerView1 setAlpha:1.0];
[pickerView2 setAlpha:0.0];
```

Where pickerView1 is visible whereas pickerView2 is not.

And wherever you want to display pickerView2 whilst hiding pickerView1 - just reverse the above.

```
[pickerView1 setAlpha:0.0];
[pickerView2 setAlpha:1.0];
```

There are other ways of doing this but this is my preferred way of doing it.

**UPDATE:**

Here's how you would implement it using your code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 1){
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 223) animated:YES];
        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 0, 0);

        if (pickerView1 == nil) { //<--- You don't need to keep calling alloc and init. This if statement only calls if you have not already declared pickerView1.
            UIPickerView *pickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
            pickerView1.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
            pickerView1.dataSource = self;
            pickerView1.delegate = self;
            [pickerView1 setTag:1];
            [self.view addSubview:pickerView1];
        }

        [pickerView1 setAlpha:1.0]; //<--- New Code
        if (pickerView2 != nil) { //<-- Checking if pickerView2 is declared yet, if not then it is already invisible. ;)
            [pickerView2 setAlpha:0.0];
        }

        //removed release call - add to dealloc method
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2){
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 273) animated:YES];
        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 0, 0);

        if (pickerView2 == nil) { //<-- again, no need to always alloc and init
            UIPickerView *pickerView2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
            pickerView2.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
            pickerView2.dataSource = self;
            pickerView2.delegate = self;
            [pickerView2 setTag:2];
            [self.view addSubview:pickerView2];
        }

        [pickerView2 setAlpha:1.0]; //<--- New Code
        if (pickerView1 != nil) { //<-- Checking if pickerView1 is declared yet, if not then it is already invisible. ;)
            [pickerView1 setAlpha:0.0];
        }
        //add release call to dealloc method
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Try this:

In your header (.h) file add this:

```
    @interface <name>ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
        UIPickerView *pickerView1;
        UIPickerView *pickerView2;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *pickerView1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *pickerView2;
    @end
```

You have to declare your pickerViews here for my previous code to work. Also note the `<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>` protocols.

Back in your implementation (.m) file, remember to synthesize:

```
@synthesize pickerView1;
@synthesize pickerView2;
```

And in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` replace:

```
UIPickerView *pickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
```

with

```
pickerView1 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
```

And replace:

```
UIPickerView *pickerView2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
```

with:

```
pickerView2 = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
```

Just remember to release them in your dealloc method:

```
    - (void)dealloc {
        [pickerView1 release];
        [pickerView2 release];
        [super dealloc];
    }
```

Your undeclared problem should be solved now.

Comment: It's getting pickerView1 & pickerView2 undeclared since it was not declared when it first enter the if condition.

Comment: @MaTaKazer `if (pickerView1/2 == nil)` should catch it if it is undeclared. Did you have the undeclared problem with your original code?

Comment: You mean try and catch? Nope it didn't as it always create 1.

Comment: @MaTaKazer - Sorry, I didn't explain that well.. Am I right in saying that you didn't have Xcode complaining about the pickerViews being undeclared with your original code?

Comment: try removing the `if (pickerView1/2 == nil)` statements and readd in the `release` statments but keep the `if` statement around the setAlpha method.

Comment: Wouldn't do. pickerView1 is not declared inside if (indexPath.row == 2). Same goes to pickerView2. It will return with undeclared error when trying to read it.

Comment: Yes. The updated 1 did solve the hiding issue. But somehow the pickerView would not be able to show up again after pickerView.hidden = YES; is called on pickerView didSelectRow: method. Then that's another whole new question. I will try to figure that out.

Comment: Manipulating the alpha property instead of hidden solved the issue.

Comment: @MaTaKazer Yes, I find the hidden property a little buggy as well. Great to know that everything is solved now! :)

Answer (score 2):

During setup:

```
pickerView1.hidden = NO;
pickerView2.hidden = YES;
```

When switching (this will work in both directions):

```
pickerView1.hidden = !pickerView1.hidden;
pickerView2.hidden = !pickerView1.hidden;
```

Cheers,
Sascha

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.view addSubview:pickerView1];

[pickerView2 removeFromSuperview];

//or

[pickerView2 setAlpha:0.0];
```

Comment: All the answer looks fine but I am getting pickerView2 undeclared. Has it got to be how my pickerView is being created?

Comment: Create an instance variable for pickerView2 in your header-file.